# Rename a file with perl

Tags: perl, path, rename

I have a file in a different folder I want to rename in perl, I was looking at a solution earlier that showed something like this:

```
#rename
for (<C:\\backup\\backup.rar>) {
    my $file = $_;
    my $new = $file . 'backup' . $ts . '.rar';  
    rename $file, $new or die "Error, can not rename $file as $new: $!";
}
```

however backup.rar is in a different folder, I did try putting "C:\backup\backup.rar" in the <> above, however I got the same error.

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR>perl backup.pl
String found where operator expected at backup.pl line 35, near "$_ 'backup'"
        (Missing operator before 'backup'?)
syntax error at backup.pl line 35, near "$_ 'backup'"
Execution of backup.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I was using

```
# Get time
my @test = POSIX::strftime("%m-%d-%Y--%H-%M-%S\n", localtime);
print @test;
```

To get the current time, however I couldn't seem to get it to [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) correctly.

What can I do to fix this? Please note I am doing this on a windows box.

Comment: Yes, that's a known and documented limitation of the rename command.

Comment: @Paul I am a little confused: **What** exactly is a known limitation of the `rename` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the actual error message. Look at the line:

```
my $new = $_ 'backup'. @test .'.rar';
```

If you want to interpolate the contents of `$_` and the array `@test` into a string like that, you need to use:

```
my $new = "${_}backup@test.rar";
```

but I have a hard time making sense of that.

Now, `strftime` returns a scalar. Why not use:

```
my $ts = POSIX::strftime("%m-%d-%Y--%H-%M-%S", localtime);
my $new = sprintf '%s%s%s.rar', $_, backup => $ts;
```

Incidentally, you might end up making your life much simpler if you put the time stamp first and formatted it as `YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS` so that there is no confusion about to which date  `04-05-2010` refers.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
my $new = $_ 'backup'. @test .'.rar';
```

probably should read

```
my $new = $file . 'backup' . @test . '.rar';
```

(You were missing a concatenation operator, and it is clearer to use the named variable from the line before than reusing `$_` there...)

Comment: Sorry -- I typed the same answer as you at the same time you did.  I even formatted it the same way.  D'oh.

Comment: This works very well, however, I get the error that we cant rename the file. 
Error, can not rename C:\backup\backup.rar as C:\backup\backup.rarbackup04-05-20
10--16-07-12.rar: No such file or directory at backup.pl line 37.

Comment: the file C:\backups\backup.rar, does exist in the C:\backups folder. Im thinking my problem may be with: #rename
for (<C:\\backup\\backup.rar>) {
 my $file = $_;
 my $new = $file . 'backup' . $ts . '.rar';  
 rename $file, $new or die "Error, can not rename $file as $new: $!";
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the string concat symbol . (the period) :

```
my $new = $_ 'backup'. @test .'.rar';
```

should be

```
my $new = $_ . 'backup' . @test . '.rar';
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight side issue but you don't need

```
for (<C:\\backup\\backup.rar>) {
   my $file = $_;
   .....
}
```

The `<  >` construct would be useful if you were expanding a wildcard but you are not.
Be thoughtful of future readers of this code (you in a year!) and write

```
my $file = 'C:\backup\backup.rar' ;
```

Note the single quotes which doen't expand backslashes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I went ahead and made the change.